# Recursive method stuck at infinite loop

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently working with mergeSort. I have come across a task that ask me specifically to NOT use temporary arrays to create a mergeSort. So recursion is the way to go. Here's my code:

UPDATE: Posted the rest of the code, by request.

```
public class RecursiveMergeSort {

public static void mergeSort(int[] list){
    mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
}
private static void mergeSort(int[] list, int low, int high){
    if(low < high){
        //recursive call to mergeSort, one for each half

        mergeSort(list, low, (high/2));
        mergeSort(list, list.length/2, high);

        int[] temp = merge(list, low, high);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, list, low, high - low + 1);
    }
}

private static int[] merge(int[] list, int low, int high){
    int[] temp = new int[high - low + 1];
    int mid = (high/2) + 1;

    if(list[low] < list[mid] && mid < list.length){
        temp[low] = list[low];
        temp[mid] = list[mid];

    }
    if(list[low] > list[mid] && mid < list.length){
        temp[low] = list[mid];
        temp[mid] = list[low];

    }
    low++;
    mid++;

    return temp;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    mergeSort(list);
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        System.out.println(list[i] + " ");
    }
}

}
```

I'm supposed to recursively divide and conquer this. However, I get stuck at a infinite loop that causes stack overflow(naturally) for the second half. And I am at a complete loss for figuring out a gentle and smooth way to tell my method to keep splitting. Bear in mind that the if statement in my snippet is supposed to be there, by courtesy of our teacher.

The low and high values are the lowest and the highest **Index** for the array passed in the method.

Need a pointer please.

Comment: Infinite recursion means you don't have the correct base cases. Think along the lines of...at which point can I solve the problem directly without recursion...

Comment: Are you modifying `list` at any point? `list.length/2` will always be lower than `high`, so it'll continue forever.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your function, as well as the line the error specifically happens on?

Comment: Think about it: Do the values you're passing to the second instance of mergeSort() ever change?

Comment: Think about `each half` of what. Try stepping through a small example with the debugger (or by hand). Make sure to go more than one level deep.

Comment: @Greg yes, at the end of the recursion i copy my temp to list.

Comment: @Solace The base case isn't the problem. When there's a single element under consideration, the function won't recourse because `low == high`.

Comment: The boundaries in your recursive call are wrong. It should be
mergeSort(list, low, (low+high)/2);
mergeSort(list, (low+high)/2+1, high);